# Show data that matches the time of day

Tags: android, time

I have this timetable that I'm getting from a webpage and I would like to display the event that matches the current time of the day. I'm currently storing each event in a `List<String>`.

The timetable looks like this:

05:00 - Event 1

06:00 - Event 2

07:10 - Event 3

08:30 - Event 4

09:00 - Event 5

10:00 - Event 6

Let's say the current time is 08:00. Now the app should display Event 2, Event 3 & Event 4 (past event, current event & next event).

Does anyone have a tip on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I won't prefer using date as String. Why don't you use timestamp instead of strings.